# Rails - what is the most efficient way to create record or update it (if the record exists)?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a MySQL relation with 3 primary keys called **golden_results**:    `platform_id, release_id, configuration_id`

All of those are also foreign keys to other relations.

Now, I also have a rake task than scans every week or so the options, and fills this relation with proper information.

There are two cases:

1. the record with this three-some-key already exists: in this case I would like to update the current record with refreshed data. I've read that there once was a create_or_update method which isn't exists now.
2. the record doesn't exists: in this case I'd like to add this record with the data.

As this may be a big access to the DB, the ideal way to achieve this would be to insert the records as **transaction**.
I've read [this article](https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/) which suggest the most proper way of achieving this from performance perspective.

My current code looks like this (this, of course, isn't best solution as described...):

```
def add_golden_result record

response= 
    GoldenResult.find_or_create_by(platform_id: record.platform_id, release_id: record.release_id, configuration_id: record.configuration_id) do |r|
        r.asr_ndr_bandwidth         =   record.asr_ndr_bandwidth
        r.normalized_ndr_bandwidth  =   record.asr_ndr_bandwidth/(10.0*record.ndr_cpu)
        r.asr_latency_bandwidth     =   record.asr_latency_bandwidth
    end

response.update(
    asr_ndr_bandwidth: record.asr_ndr_bandwidth, 
    normalized_ndr_bandwidth: record.asr_ndr_bandwidth/(10.0*record.ndr_cpu),
    asr_latency_bandwidth: record.asr_latency_bandwidth
    )
```

end

Can anyone suggest a solution? (hopefully one that doesn't asks me to write my own query, so that the rails convention will keep on being preserved using ActiveRecord).

BTW- I'm using Rails 4, with mysql2 driver.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [find_or_create_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by). I think this is exactly what you are looking for. What it will do is try to locate a record based on the given parameters and if it does not find one it will create it. Also if you do not want to immediately create the object [find_or_initialize_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_initialize_by) will call `new` instead of `create` if that is more the intended behavior.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for the reply.
I know about the   `find_or_create_by` method. 
It just that that would cause an sql-query for each record as individual, and will not support as far as I understand transaction solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `find_or_create_by` (http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by).

```
record = GoldenResult.find_or_create_by( platform_id: platform_id, 
         release_id: release_id, configuration_id: configuration_id ) do |record|
  # fill in additional data for a new record if needed
end
```

Comment: thanks for the comment.
    `find_or_create_by` doesn't provide a solution for a case in which I want to refresh the existing record (i.e. update the existing data with new one). the additional data section is used only be the   `create` module.

Also, as I mentioned to @engineersmnky, I think that performance is an issue in this implementation..

Comment: I see what you're saying, both on updates & performance. If you update the data for existing records, do you have to calculate the new data for each existing record (access release, platform, configuration), or is it just something like refreshing the timestamp to the same pre-calculated time? If the former is true, I doubt there is a bulk solution (especially one that doesn't include DB-specific SQL statements). If the latter is true, why don't you first create missing records & then update all records with the new data. 2 operations, still can be put under a single transaction.

Comment: I guess your best bet is https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import - "a library for bulk inserting data using ActiveRecord" that works for Rails 3.x and 4. According to it's wiki it can even "activerecord-import can perform on duplicate key updates (requires mysql)" - probably what you need with your updates of existing records. If that fails, you can try manually constructing MySQL-specific queries with http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer.
Well, first of all I've added the code using   `find_or_create_by`.
This was the initial version that I wrote prior to asking this question.

The purpose of the "refreshing" state is to update results on the relation based on other attributes, and later on display it.
So, not much calculation but more "refreshing" like operation to my opinion.

I've tried looking at activerecord-import and it looks great. But I wasn't able to pull an actual working example. (The on duplicate key update is exactly what I need)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an unusual problem:

```
ClassName.find_or_create_by(foo: "foo", bar: "bar", f_b_id: 1).tap do |record|
  # This runs the code on ether the found or created record
  # #tap forces a block to be ran. 
  # The object of the block is the object that it's called on.
  record.other_field = "other data"
  record.even_more_data = "even more data"
  record.save
end
```